# Saving Ember-Data records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

**Questions:**

1. This line of code `_activeAuthor.get('books').pushObject(book).save();` is processed without error in Chrome but the book is not added to the books property of the _activeAuthor instance of Ember-Data. I don't understand why?
2. The below code add the created Book to the Book property of the Chapter instance (see comment). It is a one-to-many relationship (see de Models). Ember-Data seems to automatically populate the related record on the Book instance. Is this a normal behaviour of Ember-Data? Should I let Ember-Data populate the related side of a relationship one-to-many or should I specify both sides and persist both instances?
3. I suspect that one of the issue of the below code is that the I do not handle promises properly. This code: `this.modelFor('user').get('latestChapter');` seems to return a promise. How should I handle promisses with `get()`?

**Code:**

```
createChapter: function() {
  //Getting the Author of the latestChapter or getting the first Author in the array
  var _activeAuthor = null;
  var authors = this.modelFor('user').get('authors').toArray();
  var latestChapter = this.modelFor('user').get('latestChapter');
  var latestAuthor = latestChapter.get('author');
  if (latestChapter.content) {
    _activeAuthor = latestAuthor;
  } else {
    _activeAuthor= authors[0];
  }

  var book = this.store.createRecord('book', {
    title: 'click here to name your book',
    author: _activeAuthor,
  });

  var chapter = this.store.createRecord('chapter', {
    title: 'Click here to name your chapter',
    book: book, // Add the created Book to the Book property of the Chapter instance
  });

  _activeAuthor.get('books').pushObject(book).save();
  chapter.save();
  book.save();
  this.modelFor('user').set('latestChapter', chapter).save() //Identifying the latest created chapter at the lastestChapter;
  console.log('New chapter created: ' + chapter.get('id'));
},
```

**Models:**

```
App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  authorTitle: DS.attr('string'),
  userTitle: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {inverse: 'authors', async: true}),
  books: DS.hasMany('book', { inverse: 'author', async: true}),
});


App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  icon: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  frequency: DS.attr('string'),
  chapters: DS.hasMany('chapter', { inverse: 'book', async: true}),
  author: DS.belongsTo('author', { inverse: 'books', async: true}),
});


App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  frequency: DS.attr('string'),
  unit: DS.attr('string'),
  aggregationMode: DS.attr('string'),
  dashboard: DS.attr('boolean'),
  statData : DS.attr('array'),
  book: DS.belongsTo('book', { inverse: 'chapters', async: true}),
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
`author.get('books')` will return a promise, so probably what you want to do is

```
author.get('books').then(function(books) {
    books.pushObject(book)
});
author.save();
```

If this is not an issue, could you give a jsfiddle with the whole app code? Then, it'll be easier to help! :)

2.
Every time you `get` a model's property that is `async` and is not `isLoaded` (not synced with server), ember will ask the server and yes, will populate the records in your store which is a desired behaviour :)

3.
If you have an `async` model property, then you always get a promise, so you should handle it in for example this way:

```
chapter.get('book').then(function(book) {
  // here's a book
});
```

BTW `var latestAuthor = latestChapter.get('author');` -> `chapter` doesn't have `author` property :)

Comment: This is great thanks. I now have a related question on promises in models hooks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976746/how-to-handle-promises-with-models-hooks-of-nested-routes